# How do I check for / autoremove unused imports on a Robot Framework resource?

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

I have inherited a RF project where almost every keyword comes from a beast of a god resource containing ~4k lines and hundreds of keyword definitions.

I have managed to break it by common functionality groups in 19 independent resource modules.

Nevertheless, every independent resource is currently importing all the dependencies of the original behemoth (~30 resources with extra keyword definitions and python libraries).

I think it's insane to manually go over these 19 resources x 30 dependencies one by one picking and removing the unused ones.

Is there any way to automatically find and remove unused libraries/resources referenced by a resource in Robot Framework IDE or RF plugin for Eclipse? Just like java/eclipse <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> that automatically fixes imports...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is one of the features which will be implemented in RED - Robot Editor, feel free to submit github request so it could be prioritized.